# Visual Studio Web Setup Project - deploy outside of web root (wwwroot)

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, web-deployment-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am working with Visual Studio setup projects to install web application. I am looking for a way to change the default physical file installation path. The end result I would like is a Virtual Directory called "MySite" that points to a local path on the server like "C:\Apps\MySite"

Is there a built-in option to customize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will install at the physical file installation path of the Web Site where it is installed plus the name of the virtual directory.

Answer (score 3):

edit the project file. search for keyword 'virtual' and change the value for virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with a custom action, unfortunately it's not supported as a simple setting in the setup project (as others have mentioned).

Here is an example implementation using custom action:

[Allow user to set physical directory path during Web Project deployment](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/install/WebToInstall.aspx)
(a bit old but can still be useful)