# change location of Virtual Directory in Web Setup Project

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I hope someone can enlighten me on this issue.

I have created a web setup for my web application and managed 
to deploy successfully. However, the web setup will always 
create my virtual directory under the inetpub\wwwroot directory 
(which happens to be in my C-drive).

Is there anyway I can make the web setup create the virtual 
directory in another location, eg, d-drive? I have tried to remove the installation address step of the web setup, but it still default to inetpub\wwwroot.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714309/virtual-directory-in-web-setup-project

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337211/visual-studio-web-setup-project-deploy-outside-of-web-root-wwwroot/1810407#1810407